# Why does the insert statement does not work in oracle when using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I am connected to an Oracle database using SQLAlchemy and python 2.7. I can verify that the connection string works and SELECT statements yield the right results. But when I'm trying to make an insert statement the system hangs.

Here is the code:

```
oracle_select = "INSERT INTO Demographics " \
                "(Customer_ID, Gender, Marital_Status, Children, Birth_Date, Registration_Date, Store_Id, City, " \
                "Postal_Code, Mobile_Phone, Email, Last_Update, Mobile_App, Customer_Status) " \
                "VALUES " \
                "({0}, '{1}', '{2}', {3}, to_date('{4}', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('{5}', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), " \
                "{6}, '{7}', {8}, '{9}', '{10}', to_date('{11}', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), {12}, '{13}')"

with oracle_engine.connect() as connection:
    for r in results:
        connection.execute(oracle_select.format(r.customer_id, r.gender, r.marital_status, r.children, r.birth_date,
                                               r.registration_date, r.store_id, r.city, r.postal_code, r.mobile_phone,
                                               r.email, r.last_update, r.mobile_app, r.customer_status))
```

`results` is a python array that holds corresponding objects from a previous select statement.

Comment: wrap it in try ... except to catch errors, it will tell you what's going on. Oracle is finicky about passing variables into an insert statement.

Comment: You're using string formatting for passing parameters to the query, which might not be the source of your error, but it could be. In any case you're in for a world of hurt at some point. With good luck it's just some errors. [With bad luck somebody owns your db](https://xkcd.com/327/). Use placeholders. [SQLAlchemy even offers a DB-API agnostic way for using them](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql).